# Call API from separate process in development while keeping authenticated - "Non-static method requires a target"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code

I'm porting my app's front-end to Angular(4). The current app is built in ASP.NET MVC API along jquery, all running on a single process/port in Visual Studio.

With the new Angular approach, I want to develop front-end in VS Code running in a separate process. The front end should consume the existing Visual Studio API part. I succeeded with doing this on a sample app, by modifying Allow-Headers on Web API.

Now, in my real Web API, the result that API generates depends on the authenticated user. E.g.:

```
public JsonResult GetActivitiesForScheduler()
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var activities = _aRepo.GetActivities(context, _user);
        return Json(activities.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

When the Angular process calls the Visual Studio API in debugging, the _user is null (even though I'm logged in the initial app, and both browser windows open), and the request fails with "Non-static method requires a target" error.

Is there some way how I could pass the user to API, without modifying its code?

Comment: What sort of authentication are you using right now? Typically, angularjs apps use either token based authentication such as JWTs (with or without Oauth2) or cookie based.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Identity authentication on Web MVC/API. Regarding Angular (it's Angular 2/4/5) separate project, I have not been taking the authentication into account actually. I figured once I'm done with porting and I don't need CLI etc. anymore, I could just move all into Visual Studio single solution, 2 projects - so MVC takes care of authentication of both. However, I did not test this yet.

Comment: Yah you need some infrastructure on the front end to deal with auth (i.e. storing of auth tokens in local storage for example and have interceptor to pass it along with every request or use cookie based), checkout http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ for example

Comment: I was just reading this article, which I found based on your earlier hint. Thank you, it looks like there is some hope :)